# How do you recursively delete a named directory from all volumes in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, mounted-volumes

```
echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (TemporaryFolder) do if exist "%%a" echo Removing %%a & rmdir /s /q "%%a"
```

This `for loop` deletes every directory called "TemporaryFolder" from the C:\ drive. How would I go through every mounted volume (ie. A:\ - Z:) to delete the directory "TemporaryFolder"?

Edit (This test didn't work):

```
@echo off
echo Deleting Temporary Folders... Please be patient.
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "%%ATemporaryFolder" 2^>Nul') Do RD /S/Q "%%B" 2>Nul & echo Deleting %%B
echo Successfully deleted.
pause
```

Comment: Use another `For` loop and nest that one within it.

Comment: BTW, if you run just the first part of your script, you'll see how inefficient it is, try this at the Command Prompt to see, `For /D /R "C:\" %A In (TemporaryFolder) Do @Echo "%A"`. Now try my implementation also from the Command Prompt, `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "C:\TemporaryFolder" 2^>Nul') Do @Echo "%A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my comment, here's an example of a nested `For` loop, which should do as asked:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "%%ATemporaryFolder" 2^>Nul') Do RD /S/Q "%%B" 2>Nul
```

The outer `For` loop runs the `MountVol` command which returns the mounted drive paths as `%%A`. The nested `For` loop performs the recursive directory search for those named `TemporaryFolder` located within `%%A`.

**Edit**

Here's a multiline version of the same routine with added messages:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "objFolder=TemporaryFolder"
Echo Please be patient...
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do (
    Echo Deleting directories named %objFolder% from %%A
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "%%A%objFolder%" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Echo Deleting %%B
        RD /S/Q "%%B" 2>Nul && Echo Successfully deleted %%B
    )
)
Pause
```

You should **only** modify the `objFolder` name on line `2`.

---

Instead of `MountVol`, this one uses `PowerShell` to get the drives, and matches System and Reparse Points too, *(take account that you'd need appropriate permissions to remove system directories)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "objFolder=TemporaryFolder"
Echo Please be patient...
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'PowerShell -NoP "GDr -P FileSystem|?{!$_.Used -Eq ''}|Select -Exp Root"'
) Do (Echo Deleting directories named %objFolder% from %%A
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/S/AD "%%A%objFolder%" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Echo Deleting %%B
        RD /S/Q "%%B" 2>Nul && Echo Successfully deleted %%B
    )
)
Pause
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer, I edited my answer, with a test, but it doesn't work. You wouldn't happen to know why, would you?

Comment: @sheepiiHD, It doesn't work is absolutely not an appropriate comment to make, please attempt to provide a more meaningful explanation in order that I can help you to determine what you have done wrong! And if you thought that running it from the Command Prompt constituted a proper test, then you were wrong, _because all instances of `%%` would have needed to be changed to `%`_.

Comment: It doesn't recursively go through every volume, it doesn't go through every directory, it doesn't delete anything. 

In comparison, my script takes 10-15 seconds to complete. Your script takes less than 1 second, and doesn't make any changes.

Comment: @sheepiiHD, my code works properly, your implementation of it may not but I haven't got the time to guess what the issue is. Please try harder to explain what your issue is if you wish for it to be solved! In the meantime I'm going to provide a multiline version to more closely match that in your now edited question, _(which I was not aware that you'd done)_. As a specific note, were you to run `DIR /?` at the Command Prompt, you'd note that the `/A`options `D`, `-S` and `-L` are specifically matching `Directories` which are `Not System` and `Not Reparse Points`!

Comment: @sheepiiHD, please also note that my outer loop is using `MountVol` to output volumes which are mounted, if you wanted to search through drive letters which for example have been assigned to network locations, then perhaps `MountVol` is not what you needed and your provided question parameters were incorrect.

Comment: I'm executing a bat file, I'm not doing this through command prompt. 

`First script execution: https://i.gyazo.com/e003a105459f26774bbf31e07f2554c6.mp4`

`Second script execution: 
https://i.gyazo.com/5e52fff583aef03c3e42e36edf110dba.mp4`

Perhaps, this will help.

Comment: @SheepiiHD, I have no idea how what you've posted is relevant to the question or my answers, my provided scripts do not `echo` any lines which look like that. More importantly, there is nothing in my script which deals with files, only directories, it is impossible to have files or directories which contain these characters **`:`** and **`/`**, _and Windows uses the backslash as a path separator anyhow_. What you've posted are internet URL's not folder names located on drives `A:` through `Z:`. Please post your full script and output or seek somebody else's help, otherwise I will not respond!

Comment: I have posted my "full script" in the edited example at the top. Perhaps, you're misunderstanding me. My objective is to delete all directories and subdirectories of the name "TemporaryFolder" throughout all volumes. Which means it scans the computer, and removes the contents of the directory and the directory itself. You can see for yourself that the scripts you've provided do echo lines which look like that because I showcase the .bat file before executing the script in each video. You can see in the video, nothing has changed from your code, and it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: @sheepiiHD, the scripts are tested, they work on different versions of Windows, they use the same `RD` command with `/S`  and `/Q` as your 'so called' working version. They use two different but efficient methods of cycling through the available drives which I have used on many occasions without issue. **All you have to do is use one or both of the multiline versions from my answer exactly as written, and post the exact output with an explanation of what happened. No other conversation will be entertained until you have done so.**

Comment: For the 3rd time explaining to you, I have ALREADY done this. I have put your EXACT script EXACTLY as written into a .bat file, and I have executed it, and it does not delete anything. I will not continue this conversation until you look at the executions {[1](https://i.gyazo.com/e003a105459f26774bbf31e07f2554c6.mp4)} & {[2](https://i.gyazo.com/5e52fff583aef03c3e42e36edf110dba.mp4)} because it's visual video proof that your scripts **NOT working**.